# Как написать метод, который мержит дефолтные опции с заданными?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как написать метод, который делает следующее.
У меня есть набор дефолтных свойств для каждой соц сети

```
export const defaults = {
    fb: {
    redirect_uri: window.location.href,
     appId: fbAppId,
    fields: 'id,first_name, last_name,email',
    version: 'v2.12',
    xfbml: false, 
    status: true,
    permissions: 'PROFILE_AND_EMAIL',
    disableRedirect: false,
},
    vk: {
       redirect_uri: window.location.href,
       fields: 'uid, first_name, last_name',
       version: '5.73',
       onlyWidgets: true,
       display: 'page',
      permissions: 'PROFILE_AND_EMAIL',
      appId: vkAppId,
    }
 };
```

Метод должнен принимать кастомные опции и добавлять их к дефолтным. Если дефолтное свойство не задано, то берем дефолтное.
То есть у меня должна быть возможность:

1. Передавать только одно свойство (например appId), остальные будут браться по дефолту
2. Задавать свои кастомные опции. Тогда буду получать дефолтные+кастомные опции

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

```
var options = Object.assign({}, defaults, custom, { appId: value });
```

Comment: Но в данном случае те, свойства, которых нет в дефолтных, но есть в переданных, не попадут в результатный  options

Comment: я могу передать appId снаружи, в дефолтных свойствах его нет. Нужно чтобы он попал в результирующий объект тоже

Comment: @werty "свойства, которых нет в дефолтных, но есть в переданных, не попадут" - Вы пробовали?